# How to invoke Rebol interpreter from the "Android Terminal Emulator"?

Tags: android, interpreter, rebol

I need to invoke the Rebol language interpreter from the [Android Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en) as a command that runs a script file (e.g. `rebol script-name.reb`).

So I'm not looking for an .APK app that launches only into the Rebol [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop), like that in 
https://github.com/angerangel/r3bazaar.  I'd like to be able to run it as a shell command.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous, it doesn't provide any context, plus you didn't spend much effort writing or researching your question, but I'll try to answer your question anyhow. The Android Scripting Layer doesn't have that one yet, but if you feel technically inclined enough, here are detailed instructions for adding a rebol interpreter to the Android Scripting Layer. https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/InterpreterDeveloperGuide

Comment: @user3254176 Welcome to StackOverflow.  Sorry that greetings to [new users aren't always welcoming](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/).  :-/  I edited your question, though as this isn't so much about "programming" in itself, it might be more something to come ask in the [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/) when you get 20 points *(yes, another hazing period, but it's short!)*  Don't be discouraged, this is a useful site!  Keep asking and answering, but be very familiar with the ["how to ask"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) section (for instance).

Comment: Sorry, I'm very newbie here... and also, my english is very poor :-/

Comment: @HostileFork: thank for rewriting, that's exactly what I means :-)

Comment: Does it have to run on Android Terminal Emulator? Or can it run on Terminal IDE (which is more full-featured and also open source)? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside&hl=en

Comment: I means any terminal emulator. I use an [improved]( http://code.google.com/p/connectbot-improved/) version of Connectbot

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Update: see answer.  Turns out you don't need anything special, just a little trickery to get past the +x permission rules and a version built against the NDK.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk : Rebol3 for SL4A [here](http://giuliolunati.altervista.org/Rebol3/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cross-compiled r3 for android and seems ok.

Here is the [binary](https://www.dropbox.com/s/en09qyjro71137s/r3)
and here the [source](https://github.com/giuliolunati/rebol/tree/android).

Thanks @HostileFork for help and sources.

Comment: Great.  I've incorporated the new information into my answer.  Let's see if we can get a build of that up on the downloads page.  In other good news, [you have enough points to chat now](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol-and-red), so stop by.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a native ARM build of Rebol that hasn't been put into an .APK or worrying about SL4A.  However, you can't use the current ARM console binary on http://rebolsource.net because Android uses (amongst other things) a a custom C library called "Bionic".  *(Thanks for pointing this out, @earl.)*  So you'll have to build with a toolchain targeting Android specifically, such as the [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html).

Once you have that binary, the trick is to get from downloading it to being able to put execution privileges on it.  Android mounts `/sdcard/` without allowing you to set execution privileges.  The workaround from [Building and running native code utilities on Android without ADB or rooting](http://kevinboone.net/android_native.html) is to create a new file with `cat` (as opposed to copying) under `/data/`.

For an *"it would work if not for Bionic/etc."* version: I used the browser to download the ARM console binary from http://rebolsource.net.  Following the directions from the document, I did:

```
$ cd /data/data/jackpal.androidterm/shared_prefs

$ cat /sdcard/Download/r3-linux-arm-g4d9840f.bin > rebol

$ chmod 755 ./rebol

$ ls -l
```

This successfully got me to see:

```
-rw-rw---- u0_a102  u0_a102       148 2014-02-02 20:35 jackpal.androidterm_preferences.xml
-rwxr-xr-x u0_a102  u0_a102    444960 2014-02-02 21:15 rebol
```

But due to the library issues, when I run `./rebol` I get:

> /system/bin/sh: /data/data/jackpal.androidterm/shared_prefs/rebol: No such file or directory

With a proper NDK build, that *should* work.

Comment: A minor remark re your "no such file" issue: a native ARM build for "regular" Linux/ARM alone won't suffice for Android, because Android uses, amongst other things, a custom C library (Bionic). So you'll have to build with a toolchain targeting Android specifically, such as the [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html).