# Having trouble getting Rebol3 to run on Linux-ARMhf

Tags: linux, arm, installation, rebol, rebol3

I've been able to get this to work before, because I have an identical system with it running.  I can't find what I'm missing.

I've changed permissions and checked for existence of libraries referenced via ldd, but get the following:

```
$ ls -l 
... 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 odroid odroid 449800 sep 24 18:27 r3 
... 
$ sudo ./r3 
sudo: unable to execute ./r3: No such file or directory 
$ ./r3 
bash: ./r3: No such file or directory
```

All the libraries referenced by:

```
$ ldd ./r3
```

...are in the directories and have the names as referenced by ldd's output.  I'm using the exact same executable that is working on the other system, which is identical (other than perhaps a different version number of Linux).

Comment: Not likely to be your problem (as you say Linux/ARM not Android).  But I will mention for anyone finding this that if you are on Android instead of Linux, you will get this error if you try and use a Linux ARM build instead of an [NDK build](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21518843/211160).

Comment: Are you sure it's an ARM r3, not an x86 one? I remember I've seen something similar when running a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system without 32-bit glibc

Comment: It is the exact same binary that is running on another ODROID of the same model (U3), both running Linux.  uname -a gives Linux odroid 3.8.13.26 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Jul 24 22:27:56 UTC 2014 armv71 armv71 armv71 GNU/Linux.  The other ODROID that is working is running 3.8.13.14, but I can't see how that would make this type of difference.

Comment: Also, tried "ln -s /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.13.so /lib/ld-linux.so.3" which also didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

OK. So here's the solution when encountering the following:

```
$ sudo ./r3 
sudo: unable to execute ./r3: No such file or directory
```

ARM devices running 64-bit operating systems don't generally have the 32-bit libraries installed. This can be fixed with the following commands:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf
sudo apt install libc6:armhf libncurses5:armhf libstdc++6:armhf
```

After installing those libraries, the executable should now run!